# create a mysql stored procedure in squirrel sql

Tags: mysql, squirrel-sql

I'm using squirrel sql 3.1 to create a store procedure on a mysql db. The sp works fine when I create it with other clients, but when i try with squirrel sql it gives me a bunch of errors. I tried to change the statement separator on the session properties but it says that property are not editable.
You guys have any idea? Let me know. It will be helpful for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably will want to post this question on the SQuirreL SQL Client users list (squirrel-sql-users@lists.sourceforge.net).  When/if you do, please provide an example of the stored procedure you are having trouble with in SQuirreL.

Rob Manning